# On screen keyboard in windows phone 7.1 emulator not showing

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on an application in Windows Phone 7.1. I have a page with textbox and button to take input from user. Today suddenly my on-screen keyboard (shown when clicked on textbox)  is not working. Button click is also not hitting the method in codebehind. It was working when last time I worked on app. I created another app and tested that on screen keyboard and button clicks are working there. Has someone else faced this issue and is anybody having any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just closed emulator keyboard by using "Page Down"/"Page Up" keys? There are few [keyboard shortcuts](http://dotnet-redzone.blogspot.com/2010/08/windows-phone-7-emulator-keyboard.html) for WP7 emulator.

Comment: Not sure what went wrong. But it started to work again. May be your tip worked.